# Do activated abilities queue?

Tags: diablo-iii

I've often noticed as I spam the mouse buttons, that the ability I am trying to activate doesn't seem to occur immediately, and instead may take a second or two while I finish other animations. Does this mean that I can create a short queue of abilities, or abilities always executed only one at a time?  If abilities are queue-able, how deep can I queue them?  I'd be happy to mash less if I knew my abilities were being queued. Queuing might also allow for short ability macros.

Comment: This might be character dependent. The Wizard that I play can have both of the initial AOE abilities go off almost at the same time. I also attribute the delay more to my hitting of the buttons rather than the game.

Comment: For Barbarian there is a clear delay. That my primary interest, but trying to phrase generically.

Comment: From what I can tell, up to one skill will queue.  Three quick successive uses will result in only two actual executions, but if I wait until the first execution is finished before I activate the third time, I get three executions.

Comment: Along a similar vein, I find that if you hold left click to attack with that ability (say, continually shooting Hungering Arrow), and then tap one of the other ability keys while still holding left click, your character will launch that other ability and then return to the left click one. I suspect this is true of holding any of the ability keys.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One ability will queue. If you activate an ability while another one is still active, it will execute after your current one is finished.

No more abilities will queue, however. This is what I concluded from quick tests. This is very important to the game, since it is fast paced and quick reactions are important. Queued-up abilities would hinder that immensely, since spamming buttons is an integral part of the game experience (at least... for me :P ).

Either way, queuing shouldn't have anything with what you're experiencing. What you're seeing can probably be attributed to two things:

- lag: Abilities that go off because the lag-delay is too high for a short period.
- stuns: A lot of enemies (especially later in the game) can stun your for a short time. In that case, the ability will go off immediately when you go out of stun.

Comment: +1 for "spamming buttons is an integral part of the game experience". =)